# OpenGL3.3 Mac OSX 11.4

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm actually learning OpenGL3.3 to create a multiplatform application, which draws some sprites.

Currently, I'm struggling at the compilation of vertexShader and fragShader. The OpenGL shows me information, that my device doesn't support the 3.3 version. When It's clear that it supports it.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <filesystem>
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f};
std::string readFile(const std::string &fileLoc)
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(fileLoc, std::ios::in);
    std::stringstream contex;
    if (!file.fail())
    {
        contex << file.rdbuf();
    }
    return contex.str();
}
GLuint createandComplieShader(const std::string &fileLoc, GLuint shaderType)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    std::string shaderString = readFile(fileLoc);
    const char *ShaderSource = shaderString.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &ShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    int success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        std::cerr << "Shader Error :" << infoLog << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    return shader;
}
GLuint createAndLinkShader()
{
    std::string path = std::filesystem::current_path(); 
    std::string VertexShader = "/vertShader.vert" ; 
    std::string FragmentShader = "/fragShader.vert"; 
    GLuint vertexShader = createandComplieShader(path + VertexShader , GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = createandComplieShader(path + FragmentShader , GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    int succes;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &succes);
    if (!succes)
    {
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        std::cerr << "Linking Error: " << infoLog << std::endl;
        exit(-2);
    }
    return program;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW init failed..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "A-Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Window init failed..." << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -2;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // glfwSetKeyCallback (window, HandleKeyInput);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Glew init failed..." << std::endl;
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
        return -3;
    }
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.45f, 1.0f);
    GLuint ShaderProgram = createAndLinkShader();
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    int width;
    int height;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**fragShader.vert**

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

**vertShader.vert**

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

The main binary file is located under this same folder as vertShader and fragShader

```
Shader Error :ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:2: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error
```

Comment: *"The OpenGL shows me information, that my device doesn't support the 3.3 version."* - Can you show the error log?

Comment: I'll include in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment, at the very least you should set the `glfw` window hints *before* creating the window.  So the window creation code in `main` should probably be...

```
if (!glfwInit())
{
    std::cerr << "GLFW init failed..." << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "A-Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
    .
    .
    .
```

Otherwise the `OpenGL` version associated with the newly created context can be anything (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: Yeah, That's right also I was reading shaders from the filesystem incorrectly. Thank you for your help and bits of advice. I will mark this as the solution :)